# Как верстать на Retina дисплее

Tags: layout, mac

Добрый день, решил брать себе mac с ретиной, назревает вопрос, вот есть у меня макет сверстаный на винде, что мне нужно учитывать когда я буду делать верстку? Ну то есть нужно ли будет учитывать размеры экрана, может есть какой-то мета тег чтобы верстка сама уменьшала пиксели в 2 раза в зависимости от экрана, в общем насколько сильно работа верстальшика отличается на обычном мониторе и на ретине?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некоторые методы адаптации графики под экраны с высокой плотностью пикселей:

1. Метод 1. **Использование SVG**

   .selector { background: url(../path_to_png/apple.png) no-repeat; }
   html.svg .selector { background-image: url(../path_to_svg/apple.svg); }

Идеально подходит для логотипов, иконок, а также любой векторной графики.

2. Метод 2. **CSS Media Query и свойство background-size**

   .selector { background: url(../path_to_png/apple.png) no-repeat; }
   @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
     .selector { background-image: url(../path_to_png/apple@2x.png); background-size: cover; }
   }

С помощью селектора «min-device-pixel-ratio» определяются устройства с плотностью пикселей 2 и выше, для них подключается картинка в 2 раза больше, а свойство «background-size: cover» сообщает браузеру, что имеющуюся эту картинку необходимо отмасштабировать до размеров блока сохранив пропорции.

3. Метод 3. **Замена src у картинок**

   jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
     if( 'devicePixelRatio' in window && window.devicePixelRatio == 2 ){
       var img_to_replace = jQuery( 'img.replace-2x' ).get();

   ```
   for (var i=0,l=img_to_replace.length; i<l; i++) {
     var src = img_to_replace[i].src;
     src = src.replace(/\.(png|jpg|gif)+$/i, '@2x.$1');
     img_to_replace[i].src = src;
   };
   ```

   }
   });

В HTML коде прописываем тегу  необходимый класс, ширину или высоту, чтобы увеличенная картинка не испортила дизайн.

```
<img src="../path_to_png/apple.png"
     width="200" height="200"
     class="replace-2x" />
```

Этот метод использует свойство window.devicePixelRatio для определения экрана с увеличенной плотностью, находит все картинки, которые необходимо адаптировать и заменяет их src на аналогичный, но с дополнением в «@2x».

4. Метод 4. **Cookies и решение не сервере**

   (function(){
     if( document.cookie.indexOf('device_pixel_ratio') == -1
         && 'devicePixelRatio' in window
         && window.devicePixelRatio == 2 ){

   ```
   document.cookie = 'device_pixel_ratio=' + window.devicePixelRatio + ';';
   window.location.reload();
   ```

   }
   })();

Используя JavaScript, этот метод позволяет один раз установить куку и перезагрузить страницу. Далее на основе этой куки сервер может принять решение сразу выдать адаптированную картинку для экранов с увеличенной плотностью.

Ретина
[image: Ретина]

Не ретина
[image: Не ретина]